# Day calculation from PowerQuery not correclty transformed to excel table

Tags: excel, datetime, powerquery, date-formatting, datetime-comparison

I am using PowerQuery to create a certain date time duration column. I have the following xlsx table:

[image: Table1]

DateTime1: =A2+B2

DateTIme2=D2+E2

DateDiff=F2-C2

Now I want to transform Column G "DateDiff" with PowerQuery. I select the Range A to G and click on `Data` => `From Table/Rage`

I am asked where the data is and I use the prefilled entries and just click on ok. PowerQuery opens:

[image: PQ1]

I select the column DateDiff and right-click and duplicate this column. A copy of this column appears and I select it. On datatype (where currently decimal is shown) I select "Duration". The values are transformed and I can see the following:

[image: PoQuet]

This is as expected. So first are the days, like for example 32 or 1 or 33 days, followed by the hours, minutes and seconds (and some rounding/calculation differnces in the seconds, but this can be ignored).

I click on close and load.

The table is added as follows:

[image: Table2]

The values were changed. Now column H does not show the 32,33 and 1 day anymore. The values are incorrectly shown as 1.07..., 2.08...

I do not understand why this happens? How can I get correct results here?

When I change the format to standard I get the correct numbers again. So the numbers were not changed. When I try to apply a custom format, like: T.hh:mm:ss the same wrong numbers shown. Leads to the identical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a formatting issue.
Most likely, you have col H formatted as `d.hh:mm:ss`

Unfortunately, Excel date `d` (*day*) format (or whatever the code for day is in your locale) will not display any value > `31`. At that point it will wrap back to `1`

One way to get the display you want is to turn it into a string:

```
=INT(A1) & "." & TEXT(MOD(A1,1),"hh:mm:ss")
```

You could also turn it into a string using Power Query

- Add a custom column using this formula:

  ```
   Text.From([DateDiff])
  ```
- Then Split that column using the `dot` as the delimiter and select the right-most delimiter only.
- Delete the unwanted columns.